# Can't release the variable in objective-c ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I have this function, and I don't use ARC:

```
-(NSString *)getDataFileDestinationPath      
{
    NSMutableString *destPath = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [destPath appendString:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]];
    [destPath appendFormat:@"/%@.%@", dataFileName, dataFileExtension];
    return destPath;
    [destPath release];
}
```

So without the release message I have a great memory leak in leaks analysis. So I added the `[destPath release];` message but when I try to use this method - as I can see during the debug process - this line of the code wasn't called at all. So after return message the control goes to the next method. Where should I implement the release function to free the memory?

Comment: First, don't prefix methods with `get`;  that is reserved for a special case (this isn't it).   Secondly, nothing after a `return` statement will ever be executed.

Comment: @bbum thanks, I forget about get prefix!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `autorelease` has been invented for.

```
return [destPath autorelease];
```

Or initially don't alloc-init the string object, just create an originally autoreleased instance:

```
NSMutableString *destPath = [NSMutableString string];
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use autorelease in this case.

```
    -(NSString *)getDataFileDestinationPath      
{
    NSMutableString *destPath = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [destPath appendString:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]];
    [destPath appendFormat:@"/%@.%@", dataFileName, dataFileExtension];
    [destPath autorelease];
    return destPath;
}
```